# Change twitter banner from url

Tags: python, tweepy

How would I go by changing the twitter banner using an image from url using tweepy library: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/v2.3.0/tweepy/api.py#L392

So far I got this and it returns:

```
def banner(self):
    url = 'https://blog.snappa.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Twitter-Header-Size.png'
    file = requests.get(url)
    self.api.update_profile_banner(filename=file.content)
```

`ValueError: stat: embedded null character in path`

It seems like filename requires an image to be downloaded. Anyway to process this without downloading the image and then removing it?

Comment: What is `api.update_profile_banner`?

Comment: It's this tweepy function https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/v2.3.0/tweepy/api.py#L392

Comment: Ah, sorry. I didn't put that together.

Comment: np, I opened the image with pillow and tried passing that. Returned: 

TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not PngImageFile

Comment: Doesn't look like you can do it without downloading the file

Comment: You can. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at library's code you can do what you want.

```
def update_profile_banner(self, filename, *args, **kargs):
    f = kargs.pop('file', None)
```

So what you need to do is supply the filename and the file kwarg:

```
filename = url.split('/')[-1]
self.api.update_profile_banner(filename, file=file.content)
```

Comment: This may not be 100% correct, but you can probably figure out the file-like object from here.

Comment: code for someone who's having the same problem: 
 def banner(self, name):
  url = 'file_url'
  file = requests.get(url)
  temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".png")
  try:
   temp.write(file.content)
   self.api.update_profile_banner(filename=temp.name)
  finally:
   temp.close()

Comment: Splitting the filename returns:   File "/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 1310, in _pack_image
    f.seek(0, 2)  # Seek to end of file
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek'

Comment: I think it's easier with tempfile since it gets deleted once it's closed

Comment: @Alex You should post that code as answer, it will be far more visible that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tempfile

def banner():
    url = 'file_url'
    file = requests.get(url)
    temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".png")
    try:
        temp.write(file.content)         
        self.api.update_profile_banner(filename=temp.name)
    finally:
        temp.close()
```